# Mots pour la prononciation des voyelles

Tags: prononciation, terminologie, linguistique, demande-de-mot, voyelles

Dans plusieurs langages, la différence entre voyelles de type ***é*** et ***è*** est donnée par les mots correspondants à *ouvert* et *fermé*.

J'ai remarqué que les Français que j'ai rencontrés ne connaissent pas de mots pour cette différence, et j'ai déjà vu sur ce site quelqu'un utiliser long/court qui est une chose totalement différente.

Existe-t-il un mot correct pour cette différence ?
Si oui, pourquoi n'est-il pas connu et utilisé ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

En phonétique, le [trait significatif de distinction](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Feature_%28linguistics%29) entre *é* `[e]` et *è* `[ɛ]` est appelé *aperture*. On appelle généralement l'aperture de `[e]` *semi-fermée* et celle de `[ɛ]` *semi-ouverte*. Pour plus de détails voir [wikipedia:en](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Vowel) et [wikipédia:fr](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Voyelle).

Ces termes restent toutefois assez particuliers à la linguistique ne sont pas passés dans le langage courant. Quant au *pourquoi* c'est certainement parce que ce n'est pas un sujet de discussion courant entre non-linguistes.

Comment: La derniere phrase n'est pas suffisante pour moi, parce que dans d'autres pays les mots linguistiques sont bien utilises dans des cours des langues, des chorales, etc.

Comment: @Phira : C'est peut-être un terme connu des choristes français, mais ça ne représente pas forcément tant de monde que ça. Pour les cours de langues, c'est probablement plus nécéssaire pour désigner des phénomènes inconnus spécifiques d'une langue étrangère, alors qu'en français, il pourrait suffire de dire « c'est plus comme `è` ». *Aiguë* me vient à l'esprit.

Comment: @Phira Et ils sont utilisés de même en France par ceux qui en ont besoin (cours de langues, chant, etc.)

Answer (score 8):

Les termes techniques de phonétique pour ces deux sortes de voyelles sont respectivement **semi-ouverte** (ɛ: *cèpe* en français, *net* en anglais) et **semi-fermée** (e: *thé* en français, inutilisé en anglais).

La même distinction existe respectivement entre:

- j***eu***ne et p***eu***
- ***eau*** et s***o***rt

Voir [sur Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ouverte_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie) pour les autres voyelles.